# How do i set JSON as the default for a WCF service

Tags: c#, json, wcf

How do i set JSON as the default for a WCF service?

I know that to return the data as JSON instead of XML I can use:

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Customers/{id}", Method = "PUT",
 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Is there a way that i can just have JSON as the default so that i don't need to specify the format for each method?

Comment: This may help you http://damianblog.com/2008/10/31/wcf-rest-dynamic-response/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonEndpoint">

     do not specify enableWebScript or UriTemplate will not work 

      <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="name">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```